# Append does nothing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to add an element after removing another:

```js
$("a.III").click( function(e) {
    var element = '<div class="tagul" data-tagul-src="//cdn.tagul.com/json/6vvgt1xyerus"></div>';

    e.preventDefault();
    $("div.tagul").fadeOut("slow", function(e) {
        $("div.tagul").remove();
        $("span.content.left").append(element);
        $("div.tagul").fadeIn("slow");
    })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="content left" style="float: left;">
  <div class="tagul" data-tagul-src="//cdn.tagul.com/json/aup6249sa1ew"></div>
</span>
<span class="content" style="float: right">

</span>
```

Nothing happens after the older div's fadeOut. I assume I'm doing something wrong while trying to append the new element.

Comment: Why are you using jQuery 1.2.3? That's almost *10 years out of date*. Also your snippet has no `a.III` element

Comment: I'm using an animation library that doesn't support newer versions. Thanks for pointing it out though :)

Comment: You should look at changing that library. Nothing is worth the penalty of using software that's so out of date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works fine, the problem is most likely that you don't have any content in the divs you're removing/appending, so you can't see that it's working. Here's your exact code but with content in the divs so you can actually see the script working(added an `anchor` with class of `III` which I'm assuming you forgot to include in your post):

```js
$("a.III").click( function(e) {

  e.preventDefault();
  
  var element = '<div class="tagul2" data-tagul-src="//cdn.tagul.com/json/6vvgt1xyerus">Tagul 2</div>';
  
  $("div.tagul").fadeOut("slow", function(e) {
    $("div.tagul").remove();
    $("span.content.left").append(element);
    $("div.tagul2").fadeIn("slow");
  });
});
```

```css
a.III {
  display:block;
  margin-bottom:20px;
}

.tagul2 {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="III">Click me</a>

<span class="content left" style="float: left;">
  <div class="tagul" data-tagul-src="//cdn.tagul.com/json/aup6249sa1ew">Tagul</div>
</span>
<span class="content" style="float: right">
   
</span>
```

Additionally, your `fadeIn()` function for the appended element won't actually do anything because the `div` is set to display by default(essentially you're trying to fade in an element which is already visible). In order to have it fade in, you could change the class of the element you're appending, set the CSS to `display:none;` and then the element will fade in after being appended(I have made this change in my answer).